# How to display Table vertically rather than horizontally in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

New to RMarkdown and wanting to generate some tables for a project.

Consider the following code:

```
Sepal.Length           | Sepal.Width
---------------------- | -----------------
`r iris$Sepal.Length`  |`r iris$Sepal.Width`
```

When creating this table in R Markdown, the values are displayed horizontally. How would I use this to display the values as a single column?

Thanks in advance for any replies. Hopefully, a simple one.

Comment: Instead of using this raw markdown syntax, using `knitr::kable` could be a more easy option for you to render tables in html or pdf documents.

Comment: Using `kable` is preferable, but `print(as.data.frame(iris$Sepal.Length), row.names=FALSE)` and `cat(iris$Sepal.Length, sep="\n")` will work in a pinch. Using the first option has the advantage of formatting the values consistently, e.g. 5.0 instead of just 5.